# Pure Pipe not getting cached on the component level

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Does anyone know why my Pure Pipe is not getting cached on the component level? My current understanding is that:

1. Pure Pipes are created once per component that is using the Pipe, meaning if you have multiple instances of the Pipe in your HTML, it will only be created once and cached at the component level to be shared for every instance in that component.
2. Impure Pipes on the other hand are created for each instance in your template, meaning if you have multiple instances of the Pipe in your HTML, the Pipe will be created for each instance.

Reference: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3325-understanding-pipe-instantiation-life-cycles-in-angular-4-2-3.htm

However In my current Angular project **(version: 14.2.6)**, upon logging my Pure Pipe, it is being created for every instance of the Pipe inside my HTML, similarly to Impure Pipes.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a Pure and Impure Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'pure',
    pure: true, // pure is true by default so flag is not required
})
export class PurePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() {
        console.warn('Pure Pipe has been created'); // The log to show when the Pipe is created
    }

    transform(value: unknown, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
        return null;
    }
}
```

- Reuse above code for Impure Pipe and change the `pure` flag to false to make it Impure. Also change log in the constructor to indicate the Impure pipe.
- Add your Pipes inside the `declarations:[]` of your components `NgModule`.
- Call your Pure and Impure Pipes inside your component HTML:

```
<div>{{ 'Pure Pipe' | pure }}</div>
<div>{{ 'Pure Pipe' | pure }}</div>

<div>{{ 'Impure Pipe' | impure }}</div>
<div>{{ 'Impure Pipe' | impure }}</div>
```

- For me both Impure and Pure Pipes are being logged twice inside the console, anyone know why this is happening for Pure Pipes?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pure vs impure is not about caching the pipe's instance, it's about evaluating (i.e. running `transform`). Consider the following:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'somePipe',
  pure: false, // or true
})
export class SomePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }
}
```

and

```
<div>{{ someValue | somePipe }}</div>
```

If it's declared as impure, the output will change with every change detection. If it's pure, then it will be recalculated if and only if `someValue`changes.

Comment: My question is not about "Pure vs Impure", I want to know why Pure Pipe is not being cached at the component level when apparently its supposed to be, watch the video inside my reference link please

Comment: @richardrobu what can I tell you - either Ben got it wrong, or things changed since 2017, when that article was written.

Comment: @mbojko I am checking it again. Something still looks strange - does not work as expected and documented.